# Loading template not showing in Ember app

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, ember-cli

I am developing an Ember-cli app with ember 2.1.
I created a templates/loading.hbs and several other templates.
My foo template has a input that I use to send a queryParam to foo/bar.
foo/bar uses the query param to find its model:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        q: {refreshModel: true}
    },

    model: function (params) {
        if (params.q) {
            return this.store.query('client', { q: params.q });
        } else {
            return {};
        }
    }
});
```

When I go from foo to foo/bar, the model gets loaded and foo/bar gets rendered correctly, but, during the loading time, I don't get the loading template. If I hit refresh in foo/bar, then I see the loading template.

Can you help me to understand this, and how can I make sure I always get the loading template.

Thanks!

Comment: Are  you using `liquid-fire`? I'm having the same issue and have traced it down to liquid-fire. If my fix works I'll add a PR to the liquid-fire repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `liquid-fire`, the current version breaks all loading substates. I have PR'd the main repository.

https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire/pull/384

Until then, you can add the fork to your `package.json`:

```
"liquid-fire": "git@github.com:erkie/liquid-fire.git#breaking-loading-substates"
```